# How to increase Ctrl+tab cycle stack in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, tabs

Is there a setting or code to increase the default Ctrl_Tab stack before "show all 386 tabs", (which do NOT show in order visited)?  Only 5 tabs are available. (Note- if you close the 5 tabs listed in the FF switch tabs dialog, it shows the 5 previous to those.  So it is "hardwired" to record, it seems, ALL previous tabs activation order.)
[image: FF ctrl+tab window]

When you are looking around for a tab, the 5 gets used up very quickly, then you've lost your original tab!

Like Windows Alt+Tab which shows 35 then scrolls down through ALL open windows...
[image: win alt+tab window]

Thanks!

(Also posted at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1219054)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fast Tab Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fast-tab-switcher/).
Click the icon at the right end of the tabs bar to list ALL open tabs in recently accessed order, so you can go back to that tab you were working on.

You can also filter by keywords.

You can selectively close tabs you no longer need, at the same time.

This add-on lists tabs from before it was installed, unlike the other add-ons which only show a limited list of tabs which they have recorded while they are active in the current session.

[image: fast tab switcher dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

Workaround (not an answer. please don't mark down!):

Answered at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1219054

[Switch-to-previous-active-tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/switch-to-previous-active-tab/)
- Firefox addon. Button creates a clickable drop-down list of last 30 tabs in order visited, jumps to the tab (no previews but good functionality with options for current window and all windows, time visited etc.)

[image: Switch-to-previous-active-tab screenshots]

:-)

Comment: All Tabs Helper has it too, no apparent limit, but like the previous addon it must be running to record the recents.

The curious thing is, if you delete recent tabs, Firefox itself will throw up the next 5 most recent... even from before the session was started. So FIREFOX DOES remember the visited order for ALL tabs, apparently!!!

When I get time I will check all the addons to see if any of them retrieve the recents order directly from the FF storage.